Simulation of wind force on two objects of the same weight but different surface sizes
I'm trying to apply a wind force to two objects of the same weight but different surface area sizes. The larger surface object should be moving away faster, but I keep getting both objects moving away at the same speed.

Maybe I should use some other force?


The rigid body simulation is not a kind of fluid/flow simulation or anything. Forces like wind work on the object at its origin and take the weight into account, not the shape. So if they are both the same weight (and the same distance away if you would use some kind of falloff on the wind) they are moved the same by the wind. For the same reason you cannot (or at least hardly) get any kind of propeller rotation in Blender with wind and rigid bodies.
